# in spite of no comprehending vs not comprehension

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, negation, clauses

> In spite of no comprehending, she said nothing.
>
> In spite of not comprehending, she said nothing.
>
> In spite of no comprehension, she said nothing.

Which is the best and why ?

Answer (score 1):

“In spite of” is followed by either a noun clause or a present participle.

> In spite of her lack of comprehension, …
>   In spite of not comprehending, …

(By the way, *understanding* would be the preferred verb here.)

“*<s>In spite of no comprehending</s>” is wrong because that's not a valid way to use the word “no”. It can be followed by a noun to indicate the absence of something (“there is no spoon”), but it can't be followed by a verb.

“*<s>In spite of no comprehension</s>” is wrong because “no comprehension” is not meaningful here. The sentence is not about an absent comprehension, but about the absence of comprehension, specifically the absence of her comprehension. Hence the formulation “in spite of her lack of comprehension”.

Comment: So you would say that "In spite of not comprehending what was going on, she said nothing." is a poor construction?

Comment: @Catija No, not particularly. I'd tend to say “Despite not understanding …”, but your sentence is ok.